# Integrating a function on matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have a density function `f_N` which is defined as follows (`K_nu(z)` is the modified Bessel function):

[image]

I want to compute the following integral for each value of `N`:

[image]

The following is the implementation of the above in matlab.

```
for N=1:100
    syms z
    f =@(z) (1/(gamma(N)*sqrt(pi))*(z/2).^(N-0.5).*besselk(0.5-N,z));
    g = @(z) f(z).*log(f(z));
    val=integral(g,0,Inf);
```

But when I run the above code, it's always returning NaN for varoious values of `N` with the following warning:

```
Warning: Infinite or Not-a-Number value encountered
```

Can someone suggest a simple way to do this or avoid this issue?

Comment: replace `^` by `.^` and tell us what happens.

Comment: I get this error: `Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.`

Comment: You also need to replace `*` by `.*`. That dot is so that operations are element-wise

Comment: @LuisMendo: I did that and it's evaluating to a `NaN` value showing this warning `Warning: Infinite or Not-a-Number value encountered`.

Comment: I would suggest plotting your function g for a few values of N, without integrating. From the plot you should be able to see if it is what you expect, and whether the problem lies in the definition of g, or in the integration of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing what you think you are doing. Your declaration of z as a symbol will get overridden by the function handle definition. That means the integral is not a symbolic one, but a numeric one. So what you simply need to do is to drop the function handle notation "@(z)" and do the integral symbolically...

My guess, without thoroughly analysing this, is that one of the points in you integration domain [0,inf] yields a value f (x)=inf, which would destroy a numeric integration technique, but perhaps not a symbolic one.

Comment: But I need the numerical value of the integral rather than the symbolic one.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. However, in this case, the symbolic integral should just evaluate to a constant

Comment: For instance, if we try to integrate cos (t) from t =0...pi, you will get some number. But you can arrive at that number two ways... either you can integrate it symbolically to get the exact solution, or numerically to get an approximate one